# Reordering rows in table loops

Tags: r

I would like to change the order of the rows in every output table in a loop.

I am currently using `lapply` with `dcast` to obtain a set of tables, and I have tried to set up the desired order in a list, and then implement the new order in the list with `match()`.

Here is what I am trying:

```
#Setup data
mtcars1 <- head(mtcars, 10)
mtcars1$model <- rownames(mtcars1)
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(mtcars1, mtcars1, mtcars1)
df$year <- c(1975, 1983)
df$class <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,3)

#Create set of tables
tables <- lapply(split(df, df$cyl), 
                 FUN = function(d) reshape2::dcast(model + class ~ year, 
                                                   value.var = "year", length , data = df))

tables

#My output has the rows arranged according to model alphabetical order, like this:

              model  class  1975 1983
1         Datsun 710     2    2    0
2         Datsun 710     4    1    0
3         Duster 360     2    2    0
4         Duster 360     4    1    0
5     Hornet 4 Drive     3    0    2
6     Hornet 4 Drive     4    0    1
7  Hornet Sportabout     3    2    0
8  Hornet Sportabout     4    1    0
9          Mazda RX4     2    2    0
10         Mazda RX4     3    1    0
11     Mazda RX4 Wag     2    0    2
12     Mazda RX4 Wag     4    0    1
13          Merc 230     3    2    0
14          Merc 230     4    1    0
15         Merc 240D     2    0    2
16         Merc 240D     4    0    1
17          Merc 280     3    0    2
18          Merc 280     4    0    1
19           Valiant     2    0    2
20           Valiant     3    0    1
```

However, I would like to have "Hornet 4 Drive" model at the end of the table like this:

```
              model  class  1975 1983
1         Datsun 710     2    2    0
2         Datsun 710     4    1    0
3         Duster 360     2    2    0
4         Duster 360     4    1    0
7  Hornet Sportabout     3    2    0
8  Hornet Sportabout     4    1    0
9          Mazda RX4     2    2    0
10         Mazda RX4     3    1    0
11     Mazda RX4 Wag     2    0    2
12     Mazda RX4 Wag     4    0    1
13          Merc 230     3    2    0
14          Merc 230     4    1    0
15         Merc 240D     2    0    2
16         Merc 240D     4    0    1
17          Merc 280     3    0    2
18          Merc 280     4    0    1
19           Valiant     2    0    2
20           Valiant     3    0    1
5     Hornet 4 Drive     3    0    2
6     Hornet 4 Drive     4    0    1
```

What I am currently trying is:

```
#Reorder col1 names as desired

target <- c("Datsun 710", "Duster 360", "Hornet Sportabout", "Mazda RX4" , "Mazda RX4 Wag" , 
            "Merc 230", "Merc 240D", "Merc 280",  "Valiant", "Hornet 4 Drive")

table2 <- lapply(table1, FUN = function(x) 
          x[match(target, x$model), ])

table2

               model  class 1975 1983
1         Datsun 710     2    2    0
3         Duster 360     2    2    0
7  Hornet Sportabout     3    2    0
9          Mazda RX4     2    2    0
11     Mazda RX4 Wag     2    0    2
13          Merc 230     3    2    0
15         Merc 240D     2    0    2
17          Merc 280     3    0    2
19           Valiant     2    0    2
5     Hornet 4 Drive     3    0    2
```

The output above does not include all rows, but it takes out all duplicated names in the "model" column.

Does anybody have an idea on how to sort this out?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please write all the packages that you use. This makes it faster to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, this can be solved by coercing `model` to factor, re-arranging factor levels using `forcats::fct_relevel()`, and ordering by factor levels.

```
lapply(tables, function(x) {
  x[order(forcats::fct_relevel(x$model, "Hornet 4 Drive", after = Inf)), ]
})
```

> ```
> $`4`
>                model class 1975 1983
> 1         Datsun 710     2    2    0
> 2         Datsun 710     4    1    0
> 3         Duster 360     2    2    0
> 4         Duster 360     4    1    0
> 7  Hornet Sportabout     3    2    0
> 8  Hornet Sportabout     4    1    0
> 9          Mazda RX4     2    2    0
> 10         Mazda RX4     3    1    0
> 11     Mazda RX4 Wag     2    0    2
> 12     Mazda RX4 Wag     4    0    1
> 13          Merc 230     3    2    0
> 14          Merc 230     4    1    0
> 15         Merc 240D     2    0    2
> 16         Merc 240D     4    0    1
> 17          Merc 280     3    0    2
> 18          Merc 280     4    0    1
> 19           Valiant     2    0    2
> 20           Valiant     3    0    1
> 5     Hornet 4 Drive     3    0    2
> 6     Hornet 4 Drive     4    0    1
>
> $`6`
>                model class 1975 1983
> 1         Datsun 710     2    2    0
> 2         Datsun 710     4    1    0
> 3         Duster 360     2    2    0
> 4         Duster 360     4    1    0
> 7  Hornet Sportabout     3    2    0
> 8  Hornet Sportabout     4    1    0
> 9          Mazda RX4     2    2    0
> 10         Mazda RX4     3    1    0
> 11     Mazda RX4 Wag     2    0    2
> 12     Mazda RX4 Wag     4    0    1
> 13          Merc 230     3    2    0
> 14          Merc 230     4    1    0
> 15         Merc 240D     2    0    2
> 16         Merc 240D     4    0    1
> 17          Merc 280     3    0    2
> 18          Merc 280     4    0    1
> 19           Valiant     2    0    2
> 20           Valiant     3    0    1
> 5     Hornet 4 Drive     3    0    2
> 6     Hornet 4 Drive     4    0    1
>
> $`8`
>                model class 1975 1983
> 1         Datsun 710     2    2    0
> 2         Datsun 710     4    1    0
> 3         Duster 360     2    2    0
> 4         Duster 360     4    1    0
> 7  Hornet Sportabout     3    2    0
> 8  Hornet Sportabout     4    1    0
> 9          Mazda RX4     2    2    0
> 10         Mazda RX4     3    1    0
> 11     Mazda RX4 Wag     2    0    2
> 12     Mazda RX4 Wag     4    0    1
> 13          Merc 230     3    2    0
> 14          Merc 230     4    1    0
> 15         Merc 240D     2    0    2
> 16         Merc 240D     4    0    1
> 17          Merc 280     3    0    2
> 18          Merc 280     4    0    1
> 19           Valiant     2    0    2
> 20           Valiant     3    0    1
> 5     Hornet 4 Drive     3    0    2
> 6     Hornet 4 Drive     4    0    1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right all what the question is about is that you "would like to have "Hornet 4 Drive" model at the end of the table". Here is an example how you can do that:

```
df <- data.frame(num= 1:8, name= c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

name_last <- "b"

df <- rbind.data.frame(df[df$name != name_last, ], df[df$name == name_last, ])

df
  num name
1   1    a
2   2    a
6   6    c
7   7    c
8   8    d
3   3    b
4   4    b
5   5    b
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
tables_reordered<-lapply(tables, function (x) {rbind(x[which(!x$model=="Hornet 4 Drive"),], x[which(x$model=="Hornet 4 Drive"),])})
```